# C++ char arrays - same input giving different outputs

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, user-defined-functions, netezza

I have a cpp class that implements a Netezza User-defined function (documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.udf.doc/c_udf_user_defined_funcs.html?cp=SSULQD_7.2.0%2F9&lang=en)). It takes a argument that will be a string of some date format, and converts it to YYYYMMDD format. If it isn't a valid date, it will return "99991231". Whenever I run the code on some tables, I get different outputs every time for the same inputs. I assume there is some memory issue that I am not seeing.

Logically, we set the char array retval equal to the output of the date command. If it gave a null output, we set to "99991231". Then we set a temp char array to the first 9 bytes of retval (last one being the null terminator). Then we memcpy into ret->data (a char ptr of the struct we must return).

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "udxinc.h"
#include "udxhelpers.h"

using namespace nz::udx_ver2;

class Dateconvert: public Udf
{
public:

    Dateconvert(UdxInit *pInit) : Udf(pInit){}
    ~Dateconvert(){}

    static Udf* instantiate(UdxInit *pInit);

    virtual ReturnValue evaluate()
    {

      StringReturn* ret = stringReturnInfo();
      StringArg *str;
      str = stringArg(0);

      int lengths = str->length;
      char *datas = str->data;

      string tempData = datas;

      string shell_arg = tempData;
      shell_arg = "'" + shell_arg + "'";
      string cmd="date -d " + shell_arg +  " +%Y%m%d 2>/dev/null";

      FILE *ls = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
      char retval[100];
      retval[0]='n';
      fgets(retval, sizeof(retval), ls);

      if(!isdigit(retval[0]))
      {
          strcpy(retval,"99991231");
      }

      pclose(ls);

      char temp1[9];
      memcpy(temp1, retval, 8);
      temp1[8]='\0';

      ret->size = 9;
      memcpy(ret->data, temp1, 9);

      NZ_UDX_RETURN_STRING(ret);
    }
};


Udf* Dateconvert::instantiate(UdxInit *pInit)
{
    return new Dateconvert(pInit);
}
```

When I run the UDF on one distinct value in Netezza, it gives me the expected output. However, when I run it over multiple columns, the output is sometimes correct, sometimes wrong, seemingly randomly. I assume this has to be an internal memory issue. Examples:

```
   input          output
1) 8/11/2014      20140811

2) 8/11/2014      20140811
   Fri 10/17/14   20141017

3) 8/11/2014      99991231
   Fri 10/17/14   20141017

4) 8/11/2014      20140811
   Fri 10/17/14   20141017

5) 8/11/2014      20140811
   Fri 10/17/14   20141017
   9-Nov-12       20121109

6) 8/11/2014      20140811
   Fri 10/17/14   20141017
   9-Nov-12       01241109 (what?)

7) 8/11/2014      99991231
   Fri 10/17/14   20141017
   9-Nov-12       20121109
```

Anytime there is only one call of the function, it returns the correct answer. The problem arises when it is called multiple times, which I don't understand. Why would anything be carrying over? Changing the return value size to 8 from 9 at the end of the evaluate function does not solve the issue.

This is the format by which the function is called:

```
select a.val1, DATECONVERT(a.val1)
from
(
 select '8/11/2014' as val1 from calendar
 union
 select 'Fri 10/17/14' as val1 from calendar
 union
 select '9-Nov-12' as val1 from calendar
) a
```

And compile command for the UDF:

```
nzudxcompile /export/home/nz/dateconvert.cpp -o dateconvert.o --sig "Dateconvert(VARCHAR(200))" --version 2 --return "VARCHAR(200)" --class Dateconvert --user user1 --pw mypw  --db mydb
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've added the query example and compilation command. @Barry

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but you can use `strcpy()` rather than `memcpy()`, then it will automatically put the null terminator.

Comment: Why do you need to copy first to `temp1` before copying to `ret->data`?

Comment: I haven't gone through the UDF documentation, do you need to do something to allocate space for `ret->data`?

Comment: No, it does that automatically it seems by the examples. @Barmar

Comment: Nothing else jumps out at me as being an obvious problem. Does the UDF run in your own process, so you can use a debugger, or does it run in the server?

Comment: It has a debugger. What should I look for do you think? @Barmar

Comment: I would set a breakpiont immediately after `fgets()` and look at the variables as you single-step through it.

Comment: @Barmar terrible idea about `strcpy`, it will cause buffer overflow if the string is longer than the buffer

Comment: @M.M And `memcpy` won't?

Comment: @Barmar Correct, third parameter to `memcpy` limits the amount written

Comment: But his limit is the same as the length of the string.

Comment: @M.M It's not some arbitrary, user-supplied string, it's the result of the `date` command with a format that always produces 8 characters.

Comment: The string is read from a `FILE`.   I see now that maybe you only meant to talk about the second of the two `memcpy`

Comment: @M.M It's not read from a file, it's read from the output of `date -d "date" +%Y%m%d`

Comment: @Barmar `FILE`, not "file". The third argument to `fgets` has type `FILE *`.  So, tell me what happens if someone installs a `/usr/local/bin/date` that outputs 500 characters.  Or if someone accidentally uses the wrong date format string and the real `date` puts out a longer length.

Comment: @M.M That's a ridiculous thing to protect against. The code is depending on the proper working of the `date` program, if it doesn't do what it's supposed to do then all bets are off.

Comment: @M.M What happens if someone installs a version of the C library whose `memcpy` ignores the limit argument?

Comment: The program should be staticly linked to memcpy.   Anyway my point is that you suggest introducing a potential vulnerability where there previously was none.  Any call of an external executable should be treated as a possible problem vector.   Also there remains the problem of making the code more brittle: someone might come along later and change the date format without changing the length (perhaps accidentally if they use `M` instead of `m`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut to the chase, the problem here is in how you assign tempData.

```
  StringReturn* ret = stringReturnInfo();
  StringArg *str;
  str = stringArg(0);

  int lengths = str->length;
  char *datas = str->data;

  string tempData = datas;
```

StringArg does not store a NUL-terminated string, but instead provides the length and expects you to manage that yourself.

```
select a.val1, ADMIN.DATECONVERT(a.val1)
from
(
 select '09-Nov-12'::varchar(20) as val1 
 union all
 select '9-Nov-12'::varchar(20) as val1 
) a;

   VAL1    | DATECONVERT 
-----------+-------------
 09-Nov-12 | 20121109
 9-Nov-12  | 01221109
(2 rows)
```

In this example, what is happening is that the longer first string still has a character hanging around in memory when the second, shorter string is assigned to tempData.  That hanging '2' at the end gets added on like so:

```
09-Nov-12
9-Nov-122
```

Each of these are both valid inputs to *date*, which nicely explains the output you are seeing.

```
$ date -d 09-Nov-12 +%Y%m%d
20121109
$ date -d 09-Nov-122 +%Y%m%d
01221109
```

Change the assignment to use that length, and you'll avoid the problem.

```
  //string tempData = datas;
  string tempData(datas, datas+lengths);
```

And then you get the expected output:

```
select a.val1, ADMIN.DATECONVERT(a.val1)
from
(
 select '09-Nov-12'::varchar(20) as val1 
 union all
 select '9-Nov-12'::varchar(20) as val1 
) a;

   VAL1    | DATECONVERT 
-----------+-------------
 09-Nov-12 | 20121109
 9-Nov-12  | 20121109
(2 rows)
```

All that being said, I don't know that the overall approach you are taking in this UDF will work.  As I'm running it above, the rows are generated on the host, because they are hard-coded in the SQL, and  *date* is certainly available on the host.  However, you can't expect the code that runs on the MPP backend (which we often refer to as SPUs) to have the same availability of linux utilities that you will find on the host, or if they exist that they have the same capabilities.

If I move the date into an actual table, the UDF will operate on it on the SPU, and it will give me bad output because the *date* command on the SPU image is significantly different than that of the host, and doesn't understand this input format at all.

```
select a.col1, admin.DATECONVERT(a.col1) from calendar a;

   COL1    | DATECONVERT 
-----------+-------------
 09-Nov-12 | 99991231
 9-Nov-12  | 99991231
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Interesting. When I run the command on an actual table, it gives 99991231 like you said (with the occasional 20170812 thrown in?). When I add a "limit N" to the end of the query, it works as expected. I assume this is because the limit keyword causes it to operate on host instead of SPU? @ScottMcG

Comment: That seem a likely explanation.  There's probably a way to trick it into always doing that, but that will turn the MPP system into an SMP one, which would hurt performance.  But if it's just a milllion rows or so, no big deal